# Convolution of binomial distributions

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent binomial random variables with 
$$
X\sim B(n,p)\quad Y\sim B(m,p). 
$$
Let $\{Z_i\}_1^{n+m}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $Z_1\sim B(1,p)$. It is known that
$$
P^{\sum_{i=1}^nZ_i}=P^X,\quad
P^{\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+m}Z_i}=P^Y
$$
where $P^Z$ denotes the distribution for any random variable $Z$. Let 
$$
U:=\sum_{i=1}^nZ_i\quad  V:=\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+m}Z_i.
$$

Here are my questions:

> - How can one argue that $P^{X+Y}=P^{U+V}$?
> - In general, for any random variables $X,Y,U,V$ such that 
>     $$
>   P^X=P^U,\quad P^Y=P^V
>   $$ 
>     with $U$ and $V$ being independent, when do we have 
>     $$
>   P^{X+Y}=P^{U+V}?
>   $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, by independence, we have
$$
E(e^{it(X+Y)})=E(e^{itX})E(e^{itY})
=E(e^{itU})E(e^{itV})=E(e^{it(U+V)})
$$
which gives
$$
P^{X+Y}=P^{U+V}. 
$$

For the second question, one can see that $
P^{X+Y}=P^{U+V} 
$
if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.